# Maven not copying .class files to target while in building though build runs fine in Unix,but the same works in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Hi I have the following pom configuration for the maven compiler plugin in my parent pom.xml below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.test</groupId>
<artifactId>prj-parent</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<name>Parent</name>
<description>Parent</description>
<modules>
    <module>service</module>
    <module>web</module>
</modules>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <spring.version>4.0.4.RELEASE</spring.version>
    <spring-social.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</spring-social.version>
    <javax.validation.version>1.0.0.GA</javax.validation.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.12.6</org.projectlombok.version>
    <slf4j-log4j12-version>1.7.5</slf4j-log4j12-version>
    <spring.security.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.security.version>
    <jackson.version>2.2.2</jackson.version>
    <camel-version>2.12.2</camel-version>
    <camel-aws-version>2.13.1</camel-aws-version>
    <dozer-version>5.4.0</dozer-version>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <guava.version>14.0.1</guava.version>
    <force-api-version>28.0.0</force-api-version>
    <commons-lang-version>2.6</commons-lang-version>
    <ojdbc-version>11.2.0.3.0</ojdbc-version>
    <httpclient.version>4.3.1</httpclient.version>
    <mybatis-spring-version>1.2.2</mybatis-spring-version>
    <oracle.ucp.version>11.2.0.3</oracle.ucp.version>
    <org.hamcrest.version>1.3</org.hamcrest.version>
    <atomikos.version>3.9.3</atomikos.version>
    <spring-data-commons.version>1.8.0.RELEASE</spring-data-commons.version>
    <jta.version>1.1</jta.version>
    <rest-assured.version>2.3.1</rest-assured.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                <useIncrementalCompilation>false</useIncrementalCompilation>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.9</version>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on 
                the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.4,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>[2.1,)</versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<repositories>      
    <repository>
        <id>maven-restlet</id>
        <name>Public online Restlet repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.restlet.org</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Portfolio Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone </url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>com.springsource.repository.maven.releases</id>
        <name>Spring Framework Maven General Releases (Maven Central Format)</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

child pom

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
<artifactId>service</artifactId>
<name>service</name>
<description>service layer concerned with routing ,mapping and persistence</description>
<build>
    <finalName>service</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>run</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <tasks>
                            <copy file="src/main/resources/properties/app_${env}.properties" overwrite="true"
                                tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app.properties" />
                            <propertyfile file="${project.build.outputDirectory}/properties/app.properties">
                                <entry key="test.buildnumber" value="${project.version}" />
                            </propertyfile>
                            <!-- copy dozer files <copy todir="${dozer.directory}"> <fileset dir="src/main/resources/dozer/" 
                                /> </copy> -->
                            <!-- <copy file="src/main/resources/properties/dfc_${env}.properties" overwrite="true" tofile="${project.build.outputDirectory}/dfc.properties" 
                                /> -->
                        </tasks>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>ant</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ant-optional</artifactId>
                    <version>1.5.3-1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on 
                the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-antrun-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [1.3,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>run</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-social.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- persistence -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ucp</artifactId>
        <version>${oracle.ucp.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mybatis</groupId>
        <artifactId>mybatis-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${mybatis-spring-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency> <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId> <artifactId>transactions-jta</artifactId> <version>${atomikos.version}</version> 
        </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>com.atomikos</groupId> <artifactId>transactions-jdbc</artifactId> 
        <version>${atomikos.version}</version> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId> 
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId> <version>${jta.version}</version> </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-commons</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-data-commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- sforce apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.force.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>force-partner-api</artifactId>
        <version>${force-api-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- integration apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-aws</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-aws-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-test-spring</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-mybatis</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-spring-javaconfig</artifactId>
        <version>${camel-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- convertor apis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- other dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>${httpclient.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
        <version>${ojdbc-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>${commons-lang-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>${guava.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.dozer</groupId>
        <artifactId>dozer</artifactId>
        <version>${dozer-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j-log4j12-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
        <version>${org.hamcrest.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This one is in my parent module and I have two child modules .While building on eclipse everything works fine and I see my classes as well as resources in the target folder but while building on unix the build does not copy my class files although it states so as in the line below ,though resources get copied.The version of java I have is 1.7

Command Used in unix

mvn -X clean install package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Denv=test -Dversion=0.1

Maven Version Apache Maven 3.0.3

```
[INFO] Compiling 82 source files to /build/project/xyz/build/0.1/xyz-service/target/classes
```

can anyone Please help its a pretty weird issue I am facing !!

Comment: Can you post the complete pom.xml ?

Comment: What command line maven command are you running for the build?

Comment: command is mvn -X clean install package -Dmaven.test.skip=true -Denv=test -Dversion=0.1 though the same works on Eclipse maven build @WarrenDew

Comment: have updated parent pom also @ArunM

Comment: Remove the maven-dependency-plugin from the install phase, cause it does not make sense. The maven-install-plugin is bound to that phase. Furthermore i would suggest to start using a repository manager. The springframework releases are in Maven Central. Apart from that can you show one of your child pom`s

Comment: added child pom @khmarbaise but weird part is that the same works in Eclipse

Comment: You know that a thing [filtering for resources](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.htmlhttp://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) exists?

Comment: @khmarbaise can you elaborate I didn't get completely what you pointing at ? Also how come everything works well when the same is run via eclipse embedded maven

Answer (score 0):

Hi I finally figured it out while compiling in verbose mode .Seems like one of my class was not getting compiled due to some strange issues cause of a lombok annotation .But strange is neither javac nor maven flush any errors and signal the build to be successful ..

So I sort of corrected the class by removing the annotation and now everything looks good .. :)

> not sure the issues is with maven or javac but either should look at such scenarios as they seems to me as possible bugs

links that helped

http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201307.mbox/%3CCABN1Dbpn3vCxPiFS6SqUZsk0zkUZ9kZ=h8LHuC2qR2MoG7Azow@mail.gmail.com%3E

[javac issue](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/compiler-dev/2013-July/006902.html)